# Subquery returned more than 1 value - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am receiving the following error when run the script below. Any help would be appreciated.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Script

```
DROP TABLE ProductBase_TEMP

GO

SELECT     *
INTO            ProductBase_TEMP
FROM         PILOT.dbo.PART

GO

UPDATE    ProductBase
SET              CurrentCost =
                          (SELECT     ProductBase_temp.UNIT_LABOR_COST + ProductBase_temp.UNIT_BURDEN_COST + ProductBase_temp.UNIT_SERVICE_COST AS VISUAL_Cost
                            FROM          ProductBase INNER JOIN
                                                   ProductBase_temp ON ProductBase.ProductNumber = ProductBase_TEMP.ID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI)
WHERE     (ProductNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI =
                          (SELECT     ProductBase_temp.ID
                            FROM      ProductBase_temp INNER JOIN
                                          ProductBase ON ProductBase_temp.ID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = ProductBase.ProductNumber))
```

Thanks

Comment: What help do you need?  The error's pretty self-explanatory: the sub-query on your SET clause is returning more than one value, which is not allowed.

Comment: Actually, the problem could also be in the WHERE clause's sub-query (your formatting threw me off, I'll fix it...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the joins in your correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE ProductBase
    SET CurrentCost = (SELECT ProductBase_temp.UNIT_LABOR_COST + ProductBase_temp.UNIT_BURDEN_COST + ProductBase_temp.UNIT_SERVICE_COST AS VISUAL_Cost
                       FROM ProductBase_temp
                       WHERE ProductBase.ProductNumber = ProductBase_TEMP.ID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                      )
    WHERE (ProductNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI =
              (SELECT ProductBase_temp.ID
               FROM ProductBase_temp 
               WHERE ProductBase_temp.ID COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = ProductBase.ProductNumber
              )
          )
```

The join is to another copy of the `ProductBase` table, so you are getting lots and lots of rows (the full result set).  You want to correlated the query to the outer `ProductBase` instead.